# xss attack with img hex code

Tags: javascript, html, xss

i recently found out XSS is a big thread to my site. I have set up several measures to prevent that like filtering user input , stripping out anything relates to javascript

But i recently found out that javascript can be encoded into hex code can be used in html img code,
i tried to make it myself, i found this on a XSS prevention site:

```
<img src=&#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69 &#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27 &#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29>
```

This code is javascript:

```
javascript:alert('XSS');
```

the problem is , this code is not working properly, i cant test it out to see if this kind of stuff really works.

here's the js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CCgT3/

The problem is it should be outputted as

```
<img src="javascript:alert('XSS')">
```

But the fiddle show something like this(firebug):

```
<img &#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29="" &#x70&#x74&#x3a&#x61&#x6c&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27="" src="javascri">
```

Is there something wrong with the hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the spaces in the src attribute:

```
<img src=&#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69&#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27&#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29>
```

Then it should work.

Comment: [No this won’t](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#javascript-protocol). imgs don’t use navigate.